# Error StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork

Tags: android, json

I created android application and use `JSON` get data from server but I got the error show below:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
```

how can I fix this problem
Thank you

Comment: See my Answer bellow, hope that should work!

Comment: Cause of this exception; http://stackoverflow.com/a/6986726/1528483

Answer (score 171, accepted):

you have to insert 2 lines "StrictMode" on MainActivity Class, example's below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        
        try {
            // JSON here
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Aey.Sakon

Edit:
This answer "solves" the "problem", but it does not really explain it, which is the important part.

Modifying StrictMode is NOT a fix. As well as this exception is not really an error in program logic. It is and error in program paradigm and the exception tells you, that

***you should not be performing http calls on your main thread as it leads to UI freezing. As some other answers suggests, you should hand off the http call to AsyncTask class.***

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Changing the StrictMode really just tells the app - do not remind me of me writing bad code. It can work for debugging or in some cases where you know what you are doing but generally it is not the way to go.

Comment: Use this only for debugging, not in production mode. AsyncTask is the way to go.

Comment: Can anyone show the minor of this method for production ? thanks..

Answer (score 48):

Better to use `AsyncTask` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297485/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-sending-an-email-from-android/18297516#18297516), an Alternative for just getting rid of the `Exception` is use :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
}
```

or this :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        //Your code goes here
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
});
thread.start();
```

in your Activity where `Exception` occurs.

Comment: I would say this is a better answer that the accepted, because the alternative that it offers. As explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6986726/1528483 You should move your networking operations to a thread

Comment: Worked fine, thx so much bro!!!

Comment: @vinidog glade to here from you __Happy Programming__

Comment: @vinidog glad to hear from you *Happy Programming*

Answer (score 16):

Just add two lines after on create method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```