# Android : NetworkOnMainThreadException using Rx android and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I am getting Network on thread exception when using rx android and retrofit. Here is my code:

```
public Observable<PostVariablesModel> requestApiItem() {
        return getauthenticationtoken.getToken().flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<PostVariablesModel>>() {

            public Observable<PostVariablesModel> call(String token) {
                return service.postdata(value1, value2, value3, token);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }


    public void postdata() {
        requestApiItem()   //I think problem is here any idea?
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<PostVariablesModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        System.out.print("Complete");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        System.out.print("Fail");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(PostVariablesModel apiResult) {
                        System.out.print(apiResult.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Do we have to unsubscribe it after making http calls complete. Any idea?

The Exception is give below. I am getting this exception on onError of postdata method in code:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                      at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:170)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:136)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:171)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                      at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
                                                                      at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
                                                                      at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                                                      at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
                                                                      at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                                                                      at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                                                                      at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
                                                                      at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                                                                      at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:250)
                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMap.java:74)
                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:227)
                                                                      at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:107)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: `getToken` is executed on UI thread, it should be subscribed to schedulers.io

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 return getauthenticationtoken.getToken().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

But you can also create the call adapter with a default scheduler, and that can be Schedulers.io().

---

```
return new Retrofit.Builder()
          .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())      
          .baseUrl("http://thecatapi.com/")
          .addCallAdapterFactory(
              RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())) // <---- !!!
          .build()
```

Comment: I have corrected it but still getting the same error

Comment: well then what is the stack trace

Comment: @Lingeshwaran not showing any error on log cat application is not force closing due to it

Comment: See my updated answer it contains whole exception detail

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395417/error-strictmodeandroidblockguardpolicy-onnetwork

Comment: @Lingeshwaran allowing network calls on UI thread is **not a fix to the problem**.

Comment: @developer added "create with scheduler" example

Comment: @Lingeshwaran that is not a fix and not even a good bandaid, so no.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what was the problem?

Comment: somewhere on one of your Retrofit API endpoints, you forgot to specify `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. If you set it as the default scheduler for Retrofit requests, then you don't need to specify `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` manually on them, because they will run on background thread by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public Observable<PostVariablesModel> requestApiItem() {
        return getauthenticationtoken.getToken().flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<PostVariablesModel>>() {

            public Observable<PostVariablesModel> call(String token) {
                return service.postdata(value1, value2, value3, token);
            }
        });
    }

 public void postdata() {
        requestApiItem()   //I think problem is here any idea?
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<PostVariablesModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        System.out.print("Complete");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        System.out.print("Fail");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(PostVariablesModel apiResult) {
                        System.out.print(apiResult.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
```

**EDIT**
You can try the function `requestApiItem()` like this:

```
public Observable<PostVariablesModel> requestApiItem() {

return service.postdata(value1, value2, value3, token)
                .flatMap(new Func1<PostVariablesModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<? extends PostVariablesModel> call(PostVariablesModel yourModel) {
                        return Observable.just(yourModel);
                    }
                });
}
```

Note: You can try code above (change returned data as your Model).

Comment: You can try my **EDIT**