# Unable to connect with the azure database via android studio

Tags: java, sql, azure, android-studio, jtds

I have created a database in Azure SQl with named as USERS ,and I want to access a column named as "FullName"
Loaded jar: sqljtdc4.jar
I have searched over internet and read documentations and finally implemented this but having this unknown error

My Attempt:

```
String hostName = "ABC.database.windows.net"; 
        String dbName = "myfirst"; 
        String user = "username"; 
        String password = "abcde"; 

        String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:1433;database=%s;user=%s;password=%s;encrypt=true;"
                + "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;", hostName, dbName, user, password);

//I have tried this replacing database  with databaseName/Database/DatabaseName

        Connection connection = null;

        try{Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String SQL = "select * from dbo.USERS";


            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                 ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL)) {

                // Print results from select statement
                while (resultSet.next())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,resultSet.getString("FullName"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But getting this error:

```
 W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.400 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.400 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.401 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1108)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.401 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:235)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.401 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:356)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.402 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1034)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.402 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.403 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.403 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.404 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
2019-08-06 21:27:52.404 15125-15125/com.abc.abc W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:237)
```

Comment: Got a success with the same code. Could you please have another check with your network?

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic issue for Android App, you can not directly perform a networking operation in the main thread.

There are two SO threads as below to get the same issue with yours, you can refer to them to solve it.

1. [Error StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395417/error-strictmodeandroidblockguardpolicy-onnetwork)
2. [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

One way is as below to add the two lines.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Alternatively to create a new thread to run the code in it.

Hope it helps.