# PLAIN + IMAP + SSL Android Java - failed connection

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to connect to a mail server using the `imap` protocol over `ssl` and authorization using the `plain` method.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.***my-server-domain***");
        props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
        props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");

        final Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        login,
                        password
                );
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
        Store store = null;
        try {
            store = session.getStore("imap");
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            store.connect();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

But no matter how I try, I get either such errors:

```
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1667)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
at jakarta.mail.URLName.getHostAddress(URLName.java:502)
at jakarta.mail.URLName.hashCode(URLName.java:478)
at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:365)
at jakarta.mail.Session.getPasswordAuthentication(Session.java:889)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:325)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
```

Or one like this (if I change the settings a little somewhere):

```
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
```

I tried changing `imap`, `imaps` and so on, the port (although the server is running on 993) but still can't connect. The Internet in the application is included in the manifest, I also did a separate method for checking it, and yes, it worked.

It seems to me that I am not working correctly with the `plain` method and have not connected something in the `Properties`.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace. We can’t see the error message.

Comment: You seem to try to create a network request on the main UI thread. Just search for the errormessage and you will find dozen of similar questions explaining why you get this error and possible ways to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395417/error-strictmodeandroidblockguardpolicy-onnetwork)